# Can anyone identify the silver rangefinder-style camera in this advertisement?

Tags: old-cameras

Is the camera depicted in this photo a real camera?

Can you identify it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a [Contax G1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contax_G) interchangeable lens autofocus rangefinder camera.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. It looks like the "Contax" label on top and front may have been airbrushed out for the advertisement.

Comment: @mattdm "airbrushed", how quaint!  :)

Comment: @FreeMan You know, with the airbrush tool. :)

Comment: Nicely found, I was beginning to think it was a fake prop.